# Conversion "Optional(2023-12-19 23:11:57 +0000)" to_datetime

Tags: pandas, string-to-datetime

I have some problems with conversing this one(object type) to datetime `"Optional(2023-12-19 23:11:57 +0000)"`.

I need to get `2023-12-19 23:11:57` from that.

I tried `df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])`
and got:

```
ParserError: Unknown string format: Optional(2022-06-02 20:26:53 +0000) present at position 0
```

And also tried `df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'], format='Optional')`
and got:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: (2022-06-02 20:26:53 +0000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the full format `'Optional(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z)'`:

```
df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'], format='Optional(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z)')
print(df)

# Output
                 start_time
0 2023-12-19 23:11:57+00:00
```

Input:

```
>>> df
                            start_time
0  Optional(2023-12-19 23:11:57 +0000)
```